# Is Lisinthir still the Nase Galare heir?

Tags: peltedverse

After the end of the Chatcaavan war, Lisinthir Nase Galare

> becomes Lisinthir Lauvet Imthereli, the consort of the Chatcaavan emperor, and is granted the old Imthereli lands that his father lost.

But he's still the only child of his parents. Is he still the Nase Galare heir? It seems to be ... ignored.

<sub>(This is [M.C.A. Hogarth's](http://mcahogarth.org/) Pelted universe, aka [Peltedverse](http://mcahogarth.org/wiki/the-pelted/); the Chatcaavan war is the six books in The Princes' Game, plus the two Jubilee Summer books.)</sub>

Comment: The email on her website is haikujaguar@gmail.(com). Have you tried asking her?

Comment: I've posted a couple of questions to her "ask the author" on Goodreads, but she hasn't responded to those. I guess I can try her email...

Comment: If someone openly publishes their email, I always assume it's open season to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I emailed the author (thanks for the suggestion, Valorum), and amazingly, she replied an hour later:

> The heir to Nase Galare, unless Lisinthir kicks the bucket or his mom names a new heir, was Lisinthir. His resurrection of Imthereli creates a legal issue we're going to get to in a (near) future book, which is also when we're going to meet his parents, so I commend you on your instincts: those were excellent questions. I promise they're on my list here: I have a few books I need to square away first, then the story of Lisinthir's Eldritch status, and his heirs, is next.

(For full context, what I asked her in the email was "who is the heir to Nase Galare? Is it Lisinthir? If so, why does he only seem to think of his children as Imthereli's heirs? And why don't we meet his parents - seems like they ought to have shown up at Sediryl's investiture, at the very least? As far as I can recall, both of them should still be alive, shouldn't they?")

Comment: Looks like it's [answer season](https://images.app.goo.gl/MHvTwH7PnA8piTCJA)